# Reusable parameters NestJS OpenAPI

Tags: node.js, typescript, swagger, nestjs, openapi

Does the [NestJS OpenAPI/Swagger](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/swagger) implementation support reuse of common parameters?

This would save me from having to litter my endpoint with identical `@ApiImplicitQuery` decorators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just create your own reusable decorator:

```
const ApiRoleQuery = ApiImplicitQuery({
  name: 'role',
  enum: ['Admin', 'Moderator', 'User'],
});
```

and then use it in your controller:

```
@ApiRoleQuery
@Get()
async filterByRole(@Query('role') role) {
  // ...
}
```